# Generator Not Yielding Pandas Series Properly

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to create a new Pandas series with a generator:

```
def thal_gen(series):
    for val in series:
        yield val
    
patients['why'] = pd.Series(thal_gen(patients['sex']))
display(patients.loc[:, ['sex', 'why']].tail(20)
```

This code should create an exact duplicate of the original series. However, the two series compared side by side don't have the same values and are different lengths. 30-50 rows are fine but then it gets messed up on the final rows.

Why is this happening, shouldn't this be very straightforward?

Comment: do you need to use a generator? why not just `patients['why'] = patients['sex']`?

Comment: `(patients['sex'] == pd.Series(thal_gen(patients['sex']))).all()` check first if they are correct

Comment: I was using this code when debugging, the generator's logic is going to be more advanced but I needed to make sure the generator was working at the most basic level.

Comment: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Always [Provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example (e.g. code, **data**, errors, **current output**, **expected output**), as text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Only images of plots are okay.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently this code works:

```
def thal_gen(series):
    for val in series.values:
        yield val

patients['why'] = [x for x in thal_gen(patients['sex'])]
```

This is beyond me, if anyone knows what's going on in the background please let me know.

Comment: glad that it works, but it is not valuable to anyone else reading this question without sample input data and output data. Perhaps, someone would be able to suggest a better solution, but it is good that you grasp generators as I find them quite useful.